# count for a specific key within documents

Tags: mongodb

My document structure looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f6b0f6aaa294de8ff476bf3"),
  "BLOODGAS" : [{
      "ABG_PH" : 0.0, //<< one
      "XYZ" : 2.0,
      "PQR" : 3.0
    }]
}
{
  "BLOODGAS" : [{
      "ABG_PH" : 1.0, //<< two
      "XYZ" : 2.0,
      "PQR" : 3.0
    }, {
      "ABG_PH" : 0.0, //<< three
      "XYZ" : 1.0,
      "PQR" : 2.0
    }, {
      "ABG_PH" : 0.0, //<< four
      "XYZ" : 5.0,
      "PQR" : 6.0
    }],
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f6b0f11aa294de8ff476bf2")
}
```

Now based on the current structure I have completely **four** instances with the key `ABG_PH`

But with the following query I get a count : **2**

```
db.myCollection.find({ "BLOODGAS.ABG_PH" : 0 }).count();
```

I should get a count **3**, since I have 3 instances of `ABG_PH` with the value **0**.

What kind of query would I need to get a count of 3 with the above data.

*Update* : If this isn't possible with a straightforward query, could I use map reduce here?

Comment: You're counting documents not array elements inside your documents. Put your "BLOODGAS" array elements in a seperate collection and you're fine.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet do you mean have two _collections_ ? And then relate them together by some id like a relational database?

Comment: Yes. If you want to count embedded elements you have two options; 1) seperate collections and maintain a uni- or bi-directional relationship or 2) query all candidate documents and do the embedded element count app-side. The latter doesn't scale very well due to memory constraints but can be appropriate if you have some practical guarantees regarding candidate set size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still in the early stages of development, you might want to consider using the 2.1 dev version of Mongo which has a new [aggregation framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework). I believe for this example you would `$unwind` the BLOODGAS array and then group and count.

This feature will be in the next stable 2.2 release.

Comment: hey thanks! I just checked the docs for `unwind` [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group), like you said, it's part of `2.1`, but isn't 2.1 going to come out as stable, or I'll have to wait for a while then for 2.2 based on [this roadmap](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aroadmap-panel)

Comment: @pradeep 10gen release like the Linux kernel - odd numbers are development versions, and even are productions. So once they have stabilized the new features in 2.1 they branch that into 2.2.0..

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have 2 documents in your collection, each of them embedding relating data (BLOODGAS array). When you query the collection, you try to count the **numbers of documents** which embedded data match your query, **not the number of related BLOODGAS**.
You must split BLOODGAS into a dedicated collection to count that way :( or parse the arrays in your development language or platform. But you can not consider BLOODGAS as documents.

Comment: So do you think there isn't a straight forward query?  Do you think this is possible with `MapReduce`?

Comment: Hi Pradeep, MapReduce seems a huge solution for this problem. I would recommend having a look at grouping features (db.[name].group) which is a good way to aggregate and count embedded documents.